# Flutter Stripe Native Payment Sheet's keyboard issue

Tags: flutter, keyboard-events, flutter-stripe

I am getting issue on Flutter Stripe ^9.5.0+1
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.7, on macOS 12.6.9 21G726 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)

The problem is on native paymentsheet's keyboard.

When I add card number like
xxxx yyyy zzzz 1234
And I try to undo any letter it crashes.
Like it carshes on
xxxx yyyy zzzz 123

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.